# Node.JS Consolidate and Swig

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm trying to setup Consolidate with node(express v3.1.0), to use Swig.  I keep getting the error

> Error: Cannot find module 'swig'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
>       at require (module.js:378:17)
>       at Function.exports.swig.render (/home/jamie/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:237:50)
>       at /home/jamie/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:144:25
>       at /home/jamie/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:97:5
>       at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
>       at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)

At the top, I set it up like this

```
var express = require('express');
var cons = require('consolidate');

// assign the swig engine to .html files
console.log(cons.swig);
app.engine('html', cons.swig);

// set .html as the default extension 
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

then I make my request like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home', {
        title: "home"
    });
});
```

I have a template, home.html,  in the root directory/views

My root directory is /home/jamie/hello-world.  What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**
By the way, the console.log(cons.swig) does return something.

```
{ [Function] render: [Function] }
```

So its definitely *there*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you install the `swig` package? From the readme:

> **NOTE**: you must still install the engines you wish to use, add them to your package.json dependencies.

Comment: THAT is what I was missing. I had swig installed, just not added to the package.json.  Thanks for pointing that out!!